# Sidebar not showing properly when reducing screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having some trouble with the sidebar not showing properly when the screen gets resized for mobile.
Pressing on the burger icon the menu shows up on outside the sidebar dragging the icons with it.
I also would like to know if is possible to move the bar on the top and make it smaller somehow once on mobile view.
I thought it might be something with the position of the navbar but if change the position the header moves around and I would like to keep everything on one page without the necessity to scroll.
I apologise for the inconvenience as I'm quite the beginner.
Thank you.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Rei89/pen/ydaKOr)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black flex-column">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/el.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbarNav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
    </nav>



<header>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Hello,<br>I'm Silvia</h1>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg" type="submit">Contact Me</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
position: fixed;
background-color: black;
height: 100vh;
width: 150px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1; /* Stay On Top */
font-size: 1.2rem;}

.navbar-brand img {
position: center fixed;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 90px; 
height: 70px;}

.navbar a {
color: white;}

.fab{
color: #fec614;
margin: 10px -40px;}

body {
background: url(../img/background.jpg) center fixed; 
background-size: cover;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;}

header {
color: white;
margin-top: 250px;
margin-left: 150px; /* Same as width of sidebar */}

h1{
font-size: 4.5rem;}

.btn {
margin-top: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the `display` property in media query please check the below codepen.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjgGBe)